# "Bin" problems about receive {tcp,Socket,Bin} in communication between c# and erlang

Tags: c#, sockets, erlang

when i send data:"hello world" from c#-Part ,i received the data and put it to the test_out.txt,in which i found "hello world".should it be this without function binary_to_term? and then of course i got  error :tcp_closed and a bit of  gibberish in client.                                          ---->thanks

[server]erlang-socket-code:

```
loop(Socket) ->
  receive
    {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->
    io:format("server received binary = ~p~n",[Bin]),
    file:write_file("test_out.txt", Bin),
    B="welcome to unity3d:",
    Response=[B | Bin],
    io:format("server replying = ~p~n",[Response]),
    gen_tcp:send(Socket,term_to_binary(Response)),
```

[client]c#-sockets-code

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port);
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: got it ! i sent the wrong data from c#:TcpClient,by the way,i still wonder how the test_out.txt got the string :"hello world"

Comment: when using passive mode:{avtive,false} and gen_tcp:recv/2, 1+1=2; when using {avtive ,true} and {tcp,sock,bin} , *&?·!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `binary_to_term` before writing it to file. Binary is sequence of bytes, so writing it to file works perfectly fine.

`binary_to_term` is used, when you want to send complex Erlang terms through the network. It adds additional information.

```
1> String = "Hello".               #Five letter string
"Hello"
2> Bin = term_to_binary(String).   #Encode it with term_to_binary
<<131,107,0,5,72,101,108,108,111>> #9 bytes! You get info, that it is a list and it is of length 5
3> io:format("~s~n", [Bin]).       #print the binary as it would appear in file
k^@^EHello                           
ok
```

If you want to send string, that you will write to file, you can simply use binaries, you don't have to convert it to lists or other Erlang terms.

In Erlang socket belongs to the process, that created it. If your process ended - the socket is closed. You either didn't call `loop` recursively or the process crashed.

Comment: thank you @tkowal.data is data either in binary-style or string-style.the binary data i sent from c#-code lacks the addtional information when received by server

Comment: @brushli Additional data is needed only, if you want to use the data as Erlang term (e.g. when you send tuples from Erlang node to another Erlang node via TCP).